# matlab/octave compare vectors using dictionary order?

Tags: matlab, vector, octave, lexicographic-ordering

Is there a succinct way in Octave to compare two vectors using dictionary order (lexicographic) order?

i.e. I'd like to compare two vectors `a` , `b` by the first element, return result if they differ; otherwise compare the second element, and so on..

For example, if `a = [0 1 5]` , `b = [0 2 1]`, I'd like to have

```
a <? b
```

for some operator/function `<?` to return true.

If I simply do `a < b`, this will return a vector of logical values.

```
ans =

  0  1  0
```

Comment: If you want to test if all elements are equal: `all(a == b)`

Comment: @Naveh thanks, but I'd like to answer which vector is greater in dictionary order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following will work for both MATLAB and Octave...*

You can create a [comparison function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) like so:

```
lexlt = @(a, b) find([a < b true], 1) < find([a > b true], 1);
```

It will return true if the first vector argument is lexographically less than the second, and false otherwise (if it's greater than or equal to it). For example:

```
>> a = [0 1 5];
>> b = [0 2 1];
>> lexlt(a, a)

ans =

  logical

   0

>> lexlt(a, b)

ans =

  logical

   1

>> lexlt(b, a)

ans =

  logical

   0
```

And here's the corresponding function for a "greater than" comparison (i.e. the first argument is lexographically greater than the second):

```
lexgt = @(a, b) find([a > b true], 1) < find([a < b true], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Octave you can use [issorted](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/issorted.html):

```
result = ~isequal(a,b) && issorted([a;b],'rows');
```

In MATLAB you can use [issortedrows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issortedrows.html):

```
result = issortedrows([a;b],'strictascend')
```

Answer (score 0):

Find first index which they are not equal. Then, compare them in the specified index.

```
idx = find(a ~= b);
result = a(idx(1)) < b(idx(1)); % if length(idx) > 0
```